# Firebase query from 2 nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, concatenation

```
cards

    cars
    -- idcars
        -- type:
        -- age:
        -- user: iduser

    users
    -- iduser
     -- username
     -- usermail


    ads
    -- iduser
     -- ads1 : idcars
     -- ads2 : idcars
```

With this structure how it's possible to retrieve all ads for a user together with their own data?

Example:

```
ads1: 
type: golf
age:2
```

I'm completely new with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need to get the authenticated user and then you can use this model to just retrieve the whole `ads` branch filtering through it to have everyones ads detail (if you want)

```
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
ref.child("ads").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary // This gets the whole ad branch with all the users ad data
  let adsValue = value?["ads1"] as? String ?? "" // This is the specific value of 'ads1' node

  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: thnx but at the moment i only retrive ads1 and idcars, not all cars data...

Comment: The you need to do a for loop that will loop through each node and get the data for each user

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this,

get the user id then put it in `ref.child(yourString)`

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("iduser").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in })
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require two read operations, one for the user and one for their ads. See the Firebase [documentation for reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) and for [querying lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

If you're having trouble making this work, post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).